# Running Satchmo Store

Tags: python, django, satchmo, django-1.4

Python2.7 , Django1.4

```
 Browser: A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator.

 Server Error:

  File "/home/edinteri/public_html/old/boxdecor/admin.py", line 6, in <module>
    from edinteriores.boxdecor.models import Boxdecor, Imagens, Historico, Producto_exterior, Estado, Numeros_de_serie, Comentario, Alerta, ProjectoObra
ImportError: No module named edinteriores.boxdecor.models
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I would be willing to bet there are path issues in your settings file. However, try running the site with Django 1.3 and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: It looks like edinteriores is not on your python path.  What sort of environment are you using to serve the site?

Has the site been around for awhile or are you still developing it?

Comment: I'm using CentOS. I'm  not developing it...someone has done the website a few months (years?) ago and i'm trying to setup it! How can i put the edinteriores in my python path?

Answer (score 0):

The package name "edinteriores" is very similar to your username. You should find that your package and add it to Python path. An easy solution is

```
python manage.py ... --pythonpath=some-path
```

or to set PYTHONPATH environment variable or to extend sys.path directly in manage.py or use virtualenv.

Maybe if will be useful to recompile the package if you have moved it, in order to see correct info in traceback etc.: `cd .../edinteriores; python -m compileall -f $(pwd)`